# sql query for generating user info

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, this is what wordpress database structure is

```
userid|  key  | value
1     |name   |Roi
1     |age    |25
1     |gender |m
2     |name   |Danica
2     |age    |19
2     |gender |f
```

how can I query this in one go with this kind of result

```
userid|  name | age | gender
1     |  Roi  | 25  | m
2     | Danica| 19  | f
```

I've become rusty on SQL after many months of no practice. Please help

Comment: Self outer joins. Or GROUP BY.

Comment: Lol. sorry I didn't even saw that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some self-joins like this:

```
select 
    T.userid,
    T.value as name,
    T1.value as age,
    T2.value as gender
from your_table as T
    left outer join your_table as T1 on T1.userid = T.userid and T1.key = 'age'
    left outer join your_table as T2 on T2.userid = T.userid and T2.key = 'gender'
where T.key = 'name'
```

First select record having name for each userid, and then join to it records having same userid for age and gender.

Comment: I'd take one more step. First table for id only, then 3 separate LEFT JOINS, one for each type of value. (Just in case one id has no name value.)

Comment: this helped me. I disregarded the `where` part and replaced it with `group by T.userid`.. although the query is taking too much time for 1k users

Comment: You need to do SELECT DISTINCT too.

Comment: @jarlh, well I was thinking of it during composing the query, but found case when it will be record without name but with age and gender a bit irrealistic. ;)

Comment: @jarlh `distinct` is much more faster than `group by` thanks for this

Comment: One thing DISTINCT (which MUST be redundant here) doesn't generally help much with is performance, so I'm guessing that that's some kind of query caching. @Roi, look again at your indexes.

Comment: I'll accept this as a correct answer because it gives the result I wanted, although slow for high populated data.

Comment: @Roi, as I say, the problem is your indexes, not the query

Comment: @Strawberry yea, I didn't add an index to the table. But now I indexed the id and key, query time is back to normal (like milisecs). thanks

Comment: My distinct comment was regarding my version, with triple LEFT JOINs. Not needed if name value required and just double left joins.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, do a `GROUP BY`:

```
select id,
       max(case when key = 'name' then value end) as name,
       max(case when key = 'age' then value end) as age,
       max(case when key = 'gender' then value end) as gender,
from tablename
group by id
```

Comment: the table structure is id, key and value only

Comment: @Strawberry, better now?

Comment: Better - though this will be slower than the solution already provided

Comment: That's quite possible. OP may test both versions and chose the faster one.

Answer (score -3):

```
echo "
   <tr> 
    <td> userid</td>
     <td> name </td>
     <td> age </td>
     <td> gender </td>
  </tr> 
 <tr> 
   <td> $userid</td> 
   <td> $name </td> 
   <td> $age </td> 
   <td> $gender </td> 
</tr>
";
```